# Mathematica incorrectly giving zero for partial derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic, polynomials

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 11.1**

---

Mathematica is incorrectly reporting that the partial derivative of a certain expression is zero.

I try to compute the following:

```
D[SymmetricPolynomial[3, {x1, x2, x3, x4}], x1]
```

and I get `0`. However, if I first calculate

```
SymmetricPolynomial[3, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
= x1 x2 x3 + x1 x2 x4 + x1 x3 x4 + x2 x3 x4
```

and then

```
D[x1 x2 x3 + x1 x2 x4 + x1 x3 x4 + x2 x3 x4, x1]
```

I get the correct answer of

```
x2 x3 + x2 x4 + x3 x4
```

Any idea what is going on? Even weirder, if I use different variable names, I get the correct answer by calculating in the first way:

```
D[SymmetricPolynomial[3, {x, y, z, w}], x]
= w y + w z + y z
```

Comment: Even stranger: `D[SymmetricPolynomial[3, {x1, y, x2, z}], x1]` but `D[SymmetricPolynomial[3, {x1, x2, y, z}], x1]` does not, even though `FullForm[SymmetricPolynomial[3, {x1, x2, y, z}]]` and `FullForm[SymmetricPolynomial[3, {x1, y, x2, z}]]` look the same.

Comment: [Almost certainly a bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqXc8.png).

Comment: This is a bug that will be fixed in the upcoming 11.1 release.

Comment: Which versions are affected? Mathematica 7.0.1 gives the correct result.

Comment: I'm using 11.0.1.0

Comment: This does not seem to work either: `tt = SymmetricPolynomial[3, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
D[tt, x1]`

Comment: I'm using 10.0.1, and the problem occurs.

Comment: @ilian I don't understand what is happening.  Is there a hashing problem?

Comment: @QuantumDot `SymmetricPolynomial` was not constructing the result expression correctly, so it would falsely appear to not contain any of the variables, e.g. `FreeQ[SymmetricPolynomial[3, {x1, x2, x3, x4}], x1]` would give `True`.

Answer (score 8):

According to [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian) in a comment to the OP:

> This is a bug that will be fixed in the upcoming 11.1 release.

- Versions where the bug is present: 9.0.1, 10.0.1, v11.0.1
- Versions where the bug is not present: 7.0.1, 8.0.4

Comment: Has been fixed in 11.1 as released.